# SceneKit Orbital Transformations

Tags: ios, geometry, swift, geometric-arc, scenekit

So having started with SceneKit all has gone well so far until I stumbled upon transformations, thinking that it would be like CA3d* transformations on layers.

However it seems I quite wrong and transformation work quite differently with regards to how the Z-axis works.

For example I am trying to accomplish a 3d orbital style movement, similar to a carousel look. This piece of CA3D code works brilliantly to do that:

```
var trans = CATransform3DIdentity
trans = CATransform3DRotate(trans, deg * (Float(M_PI)/180), 1, 1, 0)
trans = CATransform3DTranslate(trans, 0, 0, 100)
layer.transform = trans
```

If applied to multiple objects with different "deg" values, you get a nice circular 3d orbit look.

The same with SceneKit produces different result:

```
var trans = SCNMatrix4Identity
trans = SCNMatrix4Rotate(trans,Float(angleTemp*(M_PI/180)), 1, 1, 0)
trans = SCNMatrix4Translate(trans, 0, 0, 100)
node.transform = transform
```

What happens actually is after the rotation the Z-value axis changes and translates based on the rotation applied in CAT3D + layers, however on SceneKit the Z-axis is always constant so the translation just moves them all together, so you just get a squashed look.

So I understand that this is working in true 3d space but now it seems I am having to work with Sphereical and Ellipse mathematics to do the same.

So anyone can offer me tips how to do what I am trying to do? I am now experimenting with spherical maths and using SCNMatrix4Translate but I haven't quite got the maths right yet.

I think what I need is formulas to calculate xyz for an Ellipse, I am after something very similar to this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#mediaviewer/File:Conicas1.PNG
[image]

That kind of orbit can be achieved using the CAT3D snippet above on layers.

**So long story short, I need to get an orbital layout like the above picture and need some help on it with SceneKit and/or geometry maths. All the object should rotate around a centre origin like an orbit**

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking, but perhaps part of the difference between the results of your two code snippets is that they're not using the same rotation axis? The CA version is rotating about `(1,1,0)` and the SCN version is rotating about `(0,1,0)`.

Comment: I've modified it to correct it, I was doing some trials earlier but I used the same rotation. The difference here it seems is how the Z translations work, which in CA3D with layers the Z moves based on the previous rotation.