# SceneKit Calculate Viewable Bounds?

Tags: ios, scenekit

so as per title I am trying to figure out if there is a good way to calculate the bounds of a scene as the usual frame/bounds properties don't really work in the context.

I basically need a way to check if an object has moved out of the viewable screen based on the camera settings of xFov/yFov/zNear/zFar. So far I haven't really found a good way to do so. Have I overlooked any API methods here or does this need to be calculated manually?

I hope I have made sense here if not please tell me and I will clarify further.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SCNView` conforms to `SCNSceneRenderer` which in turn has a method called `isNodeInsideFrustum:withPointOfView:` which is what you are looking for. According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SCNSceneRenderer/isNodeInsideFrustum:withPointOfView:), it returns:

> `YES` if the bounding box of the tested node intersects the view frustum defined by the `pointOfView` node; otherwise, `NO`.

---

Using it looks something like this:

```
BOOL isInside = [sceneView isNodeInsideFrustum:nodeToTest
                               withPointOfView:sceneView.pointOfView];
if (!isInside) {
    // the bounding box of nodeToTest is not in the viewport ...
}
```

Comment: aha that looks like what I need, I've seen your work on 3d graphics, I would appreciate if you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556391/scenekit-orbital-transformations